# How to reduce circle size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` which is circle in shape.I have done `animation` things with **CSS** .Now i want to do when circle go to bottom then circle `size` remain same (now this is ok for me) but when circle bounce back to top then circle reduce it's `size`.I don't know, is it possible with **CSS** ? I am very week in **JS** .Can anyone solve my problem or suggest me the right way?

[JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/7qp8cjxe/)

Thanks in advance.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="hello"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hello{
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      border:5px solid black;
      border-radius:55px;
 }
 div {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      position: relative;
     -webkit-animation-name: example; 
     -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; 
     animation-name: example;
     animation-duration: 4s;
 }
 @keyframes example {
     0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
     75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
     100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure. Is this what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/7qp8cjxe/2/

Comment: This what i wanted to do.Thanks :)

Comment: Moving this as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things. There's a JSFiddle at the bottom which shows everything I list:

1. To reduce the circle size, just add `height: <whatever>px;` and `width:<whatever>px;` to the last stage of your animation.
2. Note that if you want it to only decrease over the last section (where it bounces back up to the top), you will need to specify that the `height` and `width` values are still the starting values at the 75% stage.
3. Because you're changing the size of the circle, the animation will "jump" at the end back to its existing form. This is because, by default, CSS animations aren't persistent. Whatever changes you make only last as long as the animation before reverting to normal.
4. If you want the change to be persistent and stay after the end of the animation, you need to use `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`.

I've created an edit on your original JSFiddle with all of the above changes [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/7qp8cjxe/3/).

Answer (score 2):

Try this - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abhash2610/7qp8cjxe/4/)

```
100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px; width:50px;height:50px}
```

Comment: Nope.When circle goes to bottom it will remain same but when circle bounce back to top then it will reduce its size.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify `width` and `height` of the div in your `keyframes` to get desired effect.

```
@keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;width:100px;height:100px;}
    100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;width:50px;height:50px}
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7qp8cjxe/2/)

We are reducing the width and height of circle in the keyframe `100%` so when the ball bounces back i.e. from keyframe `75%` to `100%` ball is animated to a smaller size. Note that to keep the size of the ball same till keyframe `75%` we are again defining `height:100px` and `width:100px` in that keyframe.

Comment: it will work for both top to bottom and bottom to top, he need only in bottom to top condition.